# full text phrase-search with stop word

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I would like SQL Server to search *a phrase* "centos 8" for example. The exact match.

But since number "8" is considered a stop word, it only searches for "centos".

**Even if I use quotes**

```
 select [KEY] FROM CONTAINSTABLE(myTable, myColumn, '"centos 8"')
```

How can I make it search for a *phrase* without disabling the stop words feature completely? (very useful in other cases)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to disable the `STOPWORDS` / `STOPLIST` feature completely, rather you can just remove that specific word "8" from it if you want the search to always be able to match it.

Microsoft's Docs [ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-fulltext-stoplist-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) explain how to remove words from the default `STOPLIST`. And for general information on managing `STOPLISTS` you can read there docs [Configure and Manage Stopwords and Stoplists for Full-Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-stopwords-and-stoplists-for-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15) as well.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a more generic solution for "ignore stop words in general, but still search for them in quotes"?

Comment: @jitbit Unfortunately through my research and my understanding of how `FULLTEXT SEARCH` works in SQL Server, I don't believe so. This is because it stores the data in an `INDEX` which I don't think SQL Server currently has the capabilities to dynamically seek on for some word tokens in the `INDEX` sometimes and ignore them other times without rebuilding the `INDEX` every time. The only suggestion I can make is you execute an `ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON YourTable SET STOPLIST = OFF` before executing a search with a `STOPWORD` you want matched and then turn it back on right after.